# Texture lookup in vertex shader behaves differently on iPad device vs iPad simulator - OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ipad, ios, opengl-es, shader

I have a vertex shader in which I do a texture lookup to determine gl_Position. I am using this as part of a GPU particle simulation system, where particle positions are stored in a texture.

It seems that: `vec4 textureValue = texture2D(dataTexture, vec2(1.0, 1.0));` behaves differently on the simulator than the iPad device. On the simulator, the texture lookup succeeds (the value at that location is 0.5, 0.5) and my particle appears there. However, on the iPad itself the texture lookup is constantly returning 0.0, 0.0.

I have tried both textures of the format GL_FLOAT and GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE.

Has anyone else experienced this? The GLSL ES spec says that texture lookups can be done in both the vertex and fragment shaders, so I don't see what the problem is.

I am using the latest GM Beta of iOS SDK 4.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just tested this as well. Using iOS 4.3, you *can* do a texture lookup on the vertex shader on both the device and the simulator. There is a bit of strangeness though (which is maybe why it's not "official" as szu mentioned). On the actual device (I tested on the iPad 2) you have to do a lookup on the fragment shader as well as on the vertex shader. That is, if you are not actually using it on the fragment shader, you'll still have to reference it in some way. Here's a trivial example where I'm passing in a texture and using the red pixel to reposition the y value of the vertex by a little bit:

```
/////fragment shader
uniform sampler2D tex; //necessary even though not actually used

void main() {
  vec4 notUsed = texture2D(tex, vec2(0.0,0.0)); //necessary even though not actually used
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}

/////vertex shader
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;   
uniform sampler2D tex; 

void main() {
  float offset = texture2D(tex, texCoord).x;
  offset = (offset - 0.5) * 2.0; //map 0->1 to -1 to +1
  float posx = position.x;
  float posy = position.y + offset/8.0;

  gl_Position = vec4(posx, posy, 0.0, 1.0);  
}
```

I have a slightly fuller write-up of this at http://www.mat.ucsb.edu/a.forbes/blog/?p=453

Comment: What you have figured out must be a bug or "happy accident". On my iPad (admittedly 4.2.1), GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS returns 0, meaning one cannot do texture lookups in the vertex shader. I'm curious what value you get on your iPad2 for GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS.

Comment: Hi, my iPad 2 using 4.3.4 also returns 0 for  GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS (and 8 for both GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS and GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS). My guess is that the graphics card on the iPad 2 supports it, but for some reason the driver disables it so that there is uniform behavior on the various iOS devices. I haven't tried this on the iPhone or iPad 1 yet. The iOS iPad 4.3 simulator also reports 0 for GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, but allows you to access textures from the vertex shader normally (without adding the fake texture lookup in the fragment shader).

Comment: Huh, interesting.. as much as I'd like to use the feature, I'm too paranoid about a future piece of hardware breaking my app if my app ignores that reported value. :(

Comment: True, I wouldn't release an app to the public that made use of vertex textures. Hopefully iOS 5 will add this functionality.

Comment: It's back in iOS 7 - for all devices. And now it's official, too. Only took them 3 years to fix whatever the bug was :)

Answer (score 6):

from the official "OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS", section "Platform Notes"

"You cannot use texture lookups in a vertex shader."

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the only thing that behaves differently in the sim versus the device. I'll make you the same suggestion I make everyone else: Ignore the simulator when you need to test that things look how they should on the device. Only test things like logic, functionality, not look on the sim, and only if you can.

Comment: Right, and this is what I have been doing; but I cannot find a way to achieve the correct behaviour on the device. It is a simple texture lookup, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling GLES on the iPad (or iPhone) does not support texture look up in a vertex shader, but don't quote me.

If it does support texel lookup in vertex shaders, perhaps you have your texture coordinates clipped or wrapping? Because 1.0x1.0 is outside of the texture IIRC.

1.0x1.0 in wrapping mode should be 0.0x0.0.
1.0x1.0 in clipping should be the last texel.

Comment: Right, and in this case my texture is entirely the same 'color'. The data is 0.8 everywhere. Still getting 0,0 as the return value.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is test a simple frag shader on the same texture and try to change as little as possible in your code. If it displays right either something is wrong in the vertex shader or texel lookup is not possible.

Comment: Yea, I have the texture being displayed on a quad using a separate shader, and that works fine. I suppose the answer is that texture lookups cannot be done in the vertex shader on the iPad hardware.

Comment: It would be great if this could be confirmed. I will check through the documentation further as I've got a feeling I read this somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out myself and Texture2D **does** work on iPad (both device and simulator) under iOS 4.2 when used in the vertex shader.

My best guess is that you have mip mapping enabled, and that is the problem.  I noticed that mip-mapped lookups in the vertex shader using Texture2D work in the simulator but not on the device.  You cannot use mip maps with Texture2D in the vertex shader because there is no way for it to select which mip-map level to use.  You need to disable mip-mapping for that texture, or use Texture2DLod instead, which supports mip maps.